# Using Python telnet lib w/o logout command

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am trying to use python's telnetlib module to get information from a remote device.  Unfortunately, it looks like the remote device does not have a "logout" type of command.  So you have to manually close the connection with CTRL-] (when manually telnetting).  I tried using Telnet.close() but doesn't seem to return any data.

Suggestions?

```
HOST = "172.16.7.37"
user = "Netcrypt"
password = "Netcrypt"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("User: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
   tn.read_until("Password: ")
   tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("session \n")

print tn.read_until("NC_HOST> ")

tn.close()
```

Comment: Please add the code by editing the original question and using the code formatting tools available there.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't seem to return any data"? Where do you expect it to return something? It must have executed fine until the last line, otherwise read_until wouldn't have returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried writing the ASCII character for ***<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>*** to the telnet connection?

`tn.write('\x1d')`

Comment: would I follow it with `tn.write('quit\n')` ?

Comment: Is 'quit' a valid command for the telnet server that you're connected to? If you need to manually close the connection using Ctrl-], then writing '\x1d' (which is the ASCII value of Ctrl-]) should do the trick.

Comment: If i use `tn.write('\x1d')` it does terminate the connection.  But if I add `print tn.read_all()` after it, it just hangs.  I dont see how i can get the information back from the 'session' command i issued

Comment: well `read_eager` and `read_lazy` don't hang but they don't print anything either

Comment: Well, that would indicate that there isn't anything to read then. You shouldn't sent the `\x1d` until you've received all of the data that you one, as I imagine it will immediately close the connection.

Comment: I ended up not needing any of that.  The deal was I had to read to the prompt, issue my command, read until the next prompt.  Never needed to read_all

    `print tn.read_until('NC_HOST>')`

Comment: If you've solved your original problem, you should post an answer of your own and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not needing any of that. The deal was I had to read to the prompt, issue my command, read until the next prompt. Never needed to read_all().

Here's the working code:

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "172.16.7.37"
user = "Netcrypt"
password = "Netcrypt"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("User: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

    tn.read_until('NC_HOST>')

    tn.write("session\n")

    data = tn.read_until('NC_HOST>')

print data
```